# Flutter can't catch exception after throw exception

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I have func , after call function, I want to throw an ApiException, but I'nt catch it.

Step 1:

I'nt catch ApiException here

```dart
FutureOr<void> login({String? user, String? password}) async {
    try {
      emit(LoadingLoginState());
      await loginUseCase?.login(user, password);
    } on ApiException catch (e) {  // I'nt catch ApiException here
      emit(ErrorLoginState(errorMessage: e.errorMessage));
    } catch (_) {
      emit(ErrorLoginState(errorMessage: S.current.connectionProblem));
    }
  }
```

Step 2:

```dart
class LoginUseCase {
  final LoginRepository _loginRepository;

  LoginUseCase(this._loginRepository);

  Future<LoginResponse?>? login(String? user, String? password) =>
      _loginRepository.login(user, password);
}
```

Step 3:

```dart
abstract class LoginRepository{
  Future<LoginResponse?>? login(String? user, String? password);
}
```

Step 4:

throw ApiException()

```dart
class UserRepoImpl implements LoginRepository {
  UserApi? userApi;

  UserRepoImpl({this.userApi});

  @override
  Future<LoginResponse?>? login(String? user, String? password) async {
     throw ApiException();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To capture errors asynchroniously, you could use `.catchError`

```dart
callApi().catchError((error){
  // handle exception here
});
```

Upd: your code

```dart
FutureOr<void> login({String? user, String? password}) async {
    emit(LoadingLoginState());
    await loginUseCase?.login(user, password)
        ?.catchError(error) {
      if(error is ApiException) {
        emit(ErrorLoginState(errorMessage: e.errorMessage));
      } else {
        emit(ErrorLoginState(errorMessage: S.current.connectionProblem));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why you cant call catchError? I'll update the answer with some call

Comment: updated with code that could work. NOTE that i wrote this without IDE, sorry for any lints and misspells

Comment: I don't know, but it never calls to catchError.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the concrete implementation with a try-catch block like this:

```
class LoginUseCase {
  final LoginRepository _loginRepository;

  LoginUseCase(this._loginRepository);

  Future<LoginResponse?>? login(String? user, String? password) {
      
      try{

         _loginRepository.login(user, password);

      } on ApiException catch(e){

         print('API Exception caught');

      }
  } 
}
```